# How to migrate x86 code for x64 in MSVC C++

Tags: c++, migration, 64-bit

I have an old library targeted for x86. I need to migrate it to work with x64. But there is some pointer address issues. I am losing the pointer address when I compile for x64. For Example:

```
int main()
{
    struct MY_STRUCT *p;
    p = (struct MY_STRUCT *)malloc(sizeof(struct MY_STRUCT )); 
    int hnd = (int)p;  //at this point, it tries to assign 64 bit address to a 32 bit variable. So half of the address is gone.
    int ret;
    ret=someFunct(hnd);
}

int someFunct(int Handle)
{
    struct MY_STRUCT *p;
    p = (struct MY_STRUCT *)(Handle); //at this point, p pointer takes an address value like 0x0000000012345678. And this causes access violation exception as expected.

    return 0;
}
```

In GCC, I remember that an int variable size can be changed to 8bytes(64bit) with compiler options. In MSVC, can I do this? I can change all the variables that hold addresses to 64 bit variable but this is a big library, so it needs to be tested deeply to make sure that works as normal as the build for x86. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: That's the drawback if the code is not standard compliant... Hint: there's `intptr_t`.

Comment: C or C++? They are two very different languages with different rules and semantics.

Comment: @Ctx  yes, I can change it to intptr_t, but I've wondered If there is a way to make standard "int" 64bit size.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude c++

Comment: Then it's even worse, because in C++ you should almost never use `malloc` to allocate objects, you don't need the `struct` keyword when using structure names, and all C-style casting should immediately be seen as a flag that there's something very bad going on.

Comment: @FurkanKESKIN You cannot assume specific sizes to the standard types, only _minimum_ sizes are declared. For your purpose, `intptr_t` was specifically introduced. Otherwise, you can use the standard types `uint64_t` if you know the size you need (which you usually don't with pointers)

Comment: To get that clear, I didn't developed the library. Why someone downvotes I don't get it.

Comment: independent of migrating the code you should fix it first. `int hnd = (int)p;` never has been a good idea

Comment: While it might be unpopular, if there's more code that looks like this then you need to take it up with your tech-lead and project management, as the code needs a major refactoring to make it correct in the first place before you think about porting or migration. It's just not valid code.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 dude I totally agree with you but I did'nt developed that library.

Comment: and? its not clear why you would prefer to migrate non portable code instead of making it portable

Comment: Can you post the actual code instead? `someFunct` doesn't make sense. We need a [mcve]. Although if the original code is of the same quality as this one, you need to rewrite it from scratch anyway.

Comment: `int hnd = (int)p;` -- This is *so* wrong.  You see code like this from a developer who writes code in a bubble, without any other competent programmer(s) reviewing the code.  In addition, if `MY_STRUCT` either now or in the future, has one or members as non-POD types, `malloc` kills everything.

Comment: I'm guessing it was written by a so-so C programmer who barely had a grip on C++ at the time.  Maybe a junior programmer or two came along after and followed the existing examples... not a pretty picture, but it happens.

Answer (score 1):

> In GCC, I remember that an int variable size can be changed to 8bytes(64bit) with compiler options.

If it can, probably best not to do this, other code/libraries might not expect it. This is especially true for your headers, you shouldn't force the consumer of your library to rely on compiler flags.

> I can change all the variables that hold addresses to 64 bit variable but this is a big library, so it needs to be tested deeply to make sure that works as normal as the build for x86.

This is something you will just have to deal with if it was written wrong. There are plenty of other pitfalls, and a lot of accidental memory overwrites and truncations can go unnoticed until an unlucky day.

C and C++ have typedef's which can be useful for controlling platform specific aspects, as well as making intent clear (e.g. I know what to expect from a `uintptr_t`, and I don't expect even a `long long` to be a pointer).

Make sure you have all the warnings turned on, and I found checking on both Windows/MSVC and Linux/GCC can help spot some things due to slightly different warnings. For example:

```
int y = (int)ptr;
```

> warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'int *' to 'int'

Firstly *never* convert a pointer to any of the int types, `int`, `long`, `unsigned`, whatever. Where you do have to do it, there is `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` which will have the *correct size*, other libraries/API's might have their own types to use when working with the API (e.g. `LONG_PTR` in Windows), which should help you support all the platforms they do correctly.

Also since nothing is perfect, other libraries and APIs you use might require a different function entirely, for example the Windows API `SetWindowLong` can't handle a pointer sized value on 64bit, regardless of any typedefs you use, but Microsoft added a `SetWindowLongPtr` function that can fit a pointer.

```
SetWindowLong(window, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG)ptr); // Not going to work on 64bit
SetWindowLong(window, GWL_USERDATA, (uintptr_t)ptr); // Still not going to work
SetWindowLongPtr(window, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)ptr); // works on 32bit and 64bit
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs, two possible options here:

- If you need to perform bit-wise operations with addresses: use `uintptr_t` instead of `int`, this will make your code portable through different platforms.
- If you don't need to perform bit-wise operations with addresses: `void*` instead of `int` will be fine.

I assume this code is C (you shouldn't be handling polymorphism and memory allocation this way in C++).